# Why Django is not rendering some HTML files from Django app directory?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates

**I am new to djando and building my first project app '*accounts*' in django framework. The '*accounts*' app has a templates\accounts folder where all the .html files are residing. The problem is, django is rendering all the .html files except reso.html located in my templates directory.**
While rendering reso.html, its throwing following error when `http://127.0.0.1:8000/masterdata/` is typed in URL bar:

```
OSError at /masterdata/
[Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\Parijat\\Desktop\\Theis project\\CRM\\accounts\\templates\\accounts\reso.html'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/masterdata/
Django Version: 3.1.4
Exception Type: OSError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\Parijat\\Desktop\\Theis project\\CRM\\accounts\\templates\\accounts\reso.html'
Exception Location: C:\Users\Parijat\Desktop\Theis project\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\filesystem.py, line 23, in get_contents
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Parijat\Desktop\Theis project\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.0
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Parijat\\Desktop\\Theis project\\CRM',
 'c:\\users\\parijat\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\python39.zip',
 'c:\\users\\parijat\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\DLLs',
 'c:\\users\\parijat\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib',
 'c:\\users\\parijat\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39',
 'C:\\Users\\Parijat\\Desktop\\Theis project\\env',
 'C:\\Users\\Parijat\\Desktop\\Theis project\\env\\lib\\site-packages']
```

I tried setting up the TEMPLATE variable in setting.py so that django can search templates from my directory but everytime its throwing the same error. For example I changed

```
'DIRS': [], to 'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'accounts'],
```

[Below is an image showing the location of my .html files:-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLIQZ.png)

> Setting.py

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = 'ss3@*&2)-+e!3bxok+afpflc&j!e(6tz^z_+80a*yh)oos8@m!'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    
    
    
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'CRM.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {   
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'CRM.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL='/images/'

STATICFILES_DIRS=[

os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

]
```

> urls.py @ project directory where the same setting.py is located

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.http import HttpResponse

urlpatterns = [
   
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('accounts.urls'))
    

]
```

> urls.py @ where apps.py and admin.py is located

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
   
    path('', views.home, name = 'home'),
    path('customers/<str:pk_test>/', views.customer, name = 'customers'),
    path('product/', views.product, name= 'product' ),
    path('create/', views.create_order, name = 'create'),
    path('create/<str:pk>/', views.UpdateOrder, name = 'updateorder'),
    path('delete/<str:pk>/', views.deleteorder, name = 'delete'),
    path('plan_production/', views.planproduction),
    path('masterdata/', views.masterdata1),
]
```

> Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from . models import *
from . forms import OrderForm
from django.template import Context, Template
from django.template.loader import *


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    order_model = orders.objects.all()
    customers_model = customers.objects.all()
    total_customers = customers_model.count()
    total_orders = order_model.count()
    delivered = order_model.filter(status='delivered').count()
    pending = order_model.filter(status='pending').count()
    context = {'order':order_model, 'customers': customers_model, 'total_customers': total_customers, 'total_orders': total_orders, 'delivered': delivered, 'pending': pending}
    
    return render(request, 'accounts\index.html', context)

def customer(request, pk_test):

    customer_model = customers.objects.get(id=pk_test)
    order_model = customer_model.orders_set.all()
    order_count = order_model.count()
    context = {'customer':customer_model, 'order':order_model, 'total_order':order_count}
    return render(request, 'accounts\customers.html', context) 

def product(request):
    
    product_model = products.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'accounts\products.html', {'products':product_model}) 

    
def create_order(request):

    form = OrderForm() 
    if request.method == 'POST':
         form = OrderForm(request.POST)
    if  form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/')


    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'accounts\order_form.html', context)

def UpdateOrder(request, pk):
    order = orders.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = OrderForm(instance=order)
    if request.method == 'POST':
         form = OrderForm(request.POST, instance= order)
    if  form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/')
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'accounts\order_form.html', context)    

def deleteorder(request,pk):
    order = orders.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
         order.delete()
         return redirect('/')
    context = {'item': order}
    return render(request,'accounts\delete.html', context)    

def planproduction(request):
        return render(request,'accounts\plan_production.html')  


def masterdata1(request):
    return render(request,'accounts\reso.html')
```

> reso.html

```
{% extends 'accounts/main.html' %}
{%load static%}
{% block content %}

<div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card text-white bg-primary mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
                  <div class="card-header">Master Data</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Resource Mater Data</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Add new resources or Update the existing resources</p>
                        <a href="#" class="primary stretched-link"></a>
                    </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="card text-white bg-success mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-header">Master Data</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                       <h5 class="card-title">Skills Mater Data</h5>
                       <p class="card-text">Add new skills</p>
                       <a href="#" class="primary stretched-link"></a>
                    </div>
    </div>
</div>   
{% endblock %}
```

[Project name-CRM
Django app-accounts
Below is an image of the project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8boRo.png)

Comment: You already tried using: 'DIRS': [os.path.join (BASE_DIR, 'templates')],

Comment: Yes I did, but it did not work

Comment: remember that template is the folder where you create all your html, in your case it would be, create the carpetal templates, and from there start calling your html, example in your application would be templates/accounts/file.html

Comment: Try `DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'accounts/templates']`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your `app` to `INSTALLED_APPS` setting in `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts' # <- here
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, however, the error is still persisting. I am wondering is there any restrictions on the total number of . HTML files that can be used in the app directory?

Comment: no there is no such thing as the number of restircted html files, can you add your project structure to your question?

Comment: try moving your `html` files out of the `accounts` folder into the `templates` folder

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, return render() function not accepting my html file as an argument and I solved it by doing two things:

1. in the settings.py template DIRS I changed to ['templates'] (before I had ['anotherdirinsidemydjangofiles\templates']
2. I moved the templates folder to the main project directory (it was a sub dir inside Django's project folder and that wasn't rendering at all).